# Can I bypass an old fuse box and connect the service directly to the breaker panel?

Tags: electrical

We have an older home with a fuse box in house and also breaker box outside. This is second time now in last couple weeks that all the main house overhead lights and outlets have gone out completely. They all go to the fuse box. First time was after turning light on and off in one room, and now yesterday after using the microwave.

All our other power like stove, washer, dryer, hot water, new room addition and maybe couple other items all go straight to the breaker box and they all work just fine. I have replaced fuses and the main lights and outlets going to the fuse box still do not work.

Multiple wires all join together in the attic and 2 main wires come down into the fuse box and then after running through their just 1 main wire goes to the breaker box. The breaker is fine and not tripped. The fuse box has buzzed a few times lately when using microwave. I am thinking fuse box is maybe bad and thinking I can totally bypass the fuse box by taking the 2 wires coming from attack and attach new wiring to them and go straight to the breaker box. It should be about 8 outlets/lights on each wire coming down from attic as I went up to inspect them best I could and did not see any issues.

I want to make sure I can bypass fuse box and check what size breaker to use. I am thinking either 20amp or 30 amp. I thought may need a 30amp breaker for each wire from attic so plenty of juice. I have done some electrical work before so comfortable doing it just making sure I am thinking right about how to do this as I can not afford to pay anyone. ANy help??!?

Comment: Most house wiring has been done with #12 or #14 cable. You wouldn't ever use a 30 amp breaker on those. #14 wire calls for a 15A breaker.

Comment: A diagram would be most helpful here. The description is a bit confusing.

Comment: That buzzing is worrisome, I don't even halfway follow the description in the question, but I don't think it's a stretch to say this is one where I'd call in reinforcements - get an electrician in there.

Comment: I think we need a **lot** more info. to figure this out, and a professional would probably be a good idea. The problem could be a "really messed up old fuse box" in which case either moving all those circuits to the (presumably much newer) outside breaker panel makes sense - or replace the fuse box with a subpanel. But either of those options will require quite a bit of work and you *really need to know what you are doing*. It is also possible that there are just a couple of bad connections somewhere that have gone bad - i.e., step-by-step junction-by-junction troubleshooting needed.

Comment: Installing an oversized breaker is asking for a fire!!! If things are cobbled together as you say they are, call an electrician!!!

Comment: here is a kicker. bought a little non contact voltage tester and it beeps red at each outlet like there is juice??!!  none of the main outlets or lights are working. Again in the main part of house all these first go to fuse box inside the house then on to the breaker box outside on side of house. ALL other outlets and rooms that are new addition go straight to the breaker box and they all work perfect still but the main outlets and lights to the fuse box will NOT come back on!

Comment: again I have replaced all fuses in the old fuse box and the breaker I have flipped on my own a few times just to see if it would come back on

Comment: any more help please

Comment: Non contact voltage testers are handy no doubt but are prone to give erronous readings because they're able to detect small voltages too... You're better off using a multimeter or a voltage tester. Of the 2 non contact detectors I own, one can detect 50-1000 volts AC and the other can detect 12-1000 volts AC.

Comment: i got digital multimeter and get 0 from all outlets

Comment: should i bypass fuse box like i thought of

Comment: I still recommend getting an electrician on site before tackling this. As an electrician, I'm not comfortable, and I'm pretty sure no one else here is either, with telling you to go ahead with your plan...

Comment: Non-contact voltage detectors also don’t detect open neutral.

Comment: Is there a breaker in the breaker box that turns off the fuse box, a switch/pullout in the fusebox that turns off the breaker box, or are they completely independent of each other?